# How do I make sure a new password does not contain 3 or more characters from a previous password?

Tags: sql, security, passwords

The security office has changed the requirements for a secure password. I need to figure out how to do that. New passwords must be prevented from including a sequence of three (3) or more characters from the previous password. I store all previous passwords in a table. We use MS SQL Server. After this I will also need to encrypt the passwords.

Comment: Storing plain passwords in a table is far from secure.

Comment: What database are you using

Comment: Remember: Storing passwords (even previous ones) in a table is EVIL! That's the first thing your security-team should address!!

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords, hash them, using a real hash tool and salt. But this will prevent you from implementing this requirement.

Comment: I understand that the Passwords need to be secured. This is an old application that hasn't been touched for years. I need to fix several things. This is one of them.

Comment: Well I suppose he can still keep the previous hashed password and at the moment of changing password he will ask the user for his previous password to have the old unhashed password. Have you tried reg ex?

Comment: What programming language do you use? You said it is an old application but is it an old programming language? Some "new" programming language have security and hashing algorithm allready implemented for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the security office wants to increase security, they should switch to a slow hash algorithm with a cost factor, like  BCrypt or PBKDF2. This would do much more good than finding complex rules for passwords.

Appropriate hash algorithms will not allow to make conclusions about the original password, so you cannot tell if the same characters where used. If your application is able to find similarities, so can do an attacker. So the only possiblity to find similarities is, to ask for the old password when changing the password (which is a good thing btw.).

Complex password rules will usually not lead to more safe passwords though. People cannot remember tons of strong passwords, and such rules can interfere with good password schemes. People can get very inventive to bypass such rules, e.g. by changing the password twice, or by using weak passwords like "Password-2014" for complex rules or forced password changes. Often you end up with weaker passwords instead of stronger ones.